# Powershell CSV Variable Header

Tags: powershell, csv, active-directory

For some reason I can't seem to wrap my head around this concept.  I'm tasked with creating some type of user access review relevant to job titles.  I'm currently using the process below to get the AD user, their job title, and the group memberships for that user.  I've just never created a variable based header before.

```
$Server = "Domain Controller"
$OULocation = 'DC=TEST,DC=COM'

Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase $OULocation -Server $Server -Properties memberOf,title,name,samaccountname |

Foreach-Object{
    $var = [PSCustomObject]@{
            SAM = $_.SamAccountName
            Name = $_.Name
            Title = $_.Title
            Group = ""
        }
    $_.memberOf  |
        ForEach-Object{
            $var.Group  = (Get-ADGroup $_).samaccountname
            $var
        }

} | Export-Csv -Path C:\PS_Results\UserPermissions.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

The output is great and is expected, example of above command

```
SID, Name, Title, Group
UserSAM1, UserName1, IT Guy, IT Groups 1
UserSAM1, UserName1, IT Guy, IT Groups 2
UserSAM1, UserName1, IT Guy, IT Groups 3
UserSAM2, UserName2, Marketing Guy, Marketing Groups 1
UserSAM2, UserName2, Marketing Guy, Marketing Groups 2
UserSAM2, UserName2, Marketing Guy, Marketing Groups 3
```

However, I'm looking to change things up and make the headers the samaccountname, below that the name, job title and then all of the groups.  I have no clue why I can't seem to manipulate the CSV to create some sort of variable driven header with appropriate data under it.  I don't really have any sample works since I'm not sure where to start exactly.  It would seem each iteration of the Get-Aduser would need to be a new column with the specified variables.

I'm looking for something like this

```
UserSAM1        UserSAM2
UserName1       UserName2
IT Guy          Marketing Guy
IT Groups 1     Marketing Groups 1
IT Groups 2     Marketing Groups 2
IT Groups 3     Marketing Groups 3
```

I'm also open to any ideas on how others may have provided similar access reviews of AD

Thank you!

Comment: I think the output you have right now is the best you can get from a data analysis perspective. Those objects can be filtered and sorted at ease whereas the output you want to have is a terrible idea. Those objects will not be filterable or sortable

Comment: What @SantiagoSquarzon said, this format is probably going to give you nightmares down the road :) Can you tell us about your motivation for pivoting the data like you've described? What are you hoping to achieve with the new format?

Comment: Agreed with the 2 above and the first issue you'd get with exporting to csv is the column headers would have to be the same for it to export.

Comment: Thank you for the responses, sadly the request comes down to some weird obsession with how things should look from powers that be.  As I agree with everyone's comments; the output I already have is probably the best it's going to get.  One thing I know I'd like to accomplish is finding commonalities/differences with a job title and the ad groups assigned per user.  That might be why the format is the way "they" want it.

Comment: It's worth noting that the desired export will bring 2 additional problems, 1. Appending content to this Csv will be no easy task. 2. The array of objects to export will need to be holded in memory as a whole before exporting, stream writing to the Csv will not be possible without determining how many columns (users will be needed)

Comment: Ah, very true Santiago.  I was thinking, that's going to be a lot of holding storage until the command has finished running.

Comment: Also explains why beating up every forum, nobody has asked this question.  Or at least I couldn't find anything similar enough to help me

Comment: For the sake of helping you accomplish this task, I can post an answer unless there is a possibility for you to fight against this idea of laying the data this way?

Comment: Oh, please do not do that.  I have pulled too many rabbits out of my hat and it's is now a daily and acceptable occurrence.  I will run with the output I have created.   I just need to figure out how I'm going to cross compare all of this data, i.e I have 20 people are all the same X job with different AD group memberships sprinkled in.  Need to find the least priveleged ad groups/access needed to perform the jobs.  FYI the output is 12k rows lol

Comment: If I understand correctly, that could be accomplished using `Group-Object` on the `title` property. Worth a new question with this specific new requirement you have

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249434/discussion-between-crowbartm-and-santiago-squarzon).

Comment: Depending on how much data you're trying to parse I'd be tempted to do `Group-Object` on `title,group`